# How can i get atleat one checkbox checked in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, checkbox

Hi all i have to make atleast one check box checked for the user this is my what i am trying to do

```
     <% foreach (var item in Model)
         { %>  
             <br />
              <%:Html.CheckBox("EmployeId", new { value = item.EmployeeID })%>
              <%:Html.LabelForModel(item.EmployeeName)%>

      <%} %>
```

Script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$('#Sbmit').on('click', function () {
    if ($('.require-one:checked').size() > 0) {
        $('.error').text('You must select atleast one!').show();
    } else {
        $('.error').hide();
    }
});
```

can any one tell me how can i do this....on a button click i have to validate the checkboxes for atleast one checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I do it using jQuery Validate plugin: [**DEMO**](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)

jQuery is:

```
$("#request-form").validate({
    rules: {
        checkbox: { 
        required: 'input[type="checkbox"]:checked',
        minlength: $('input[type="checkbox"]').length();
        }
    },
    messages: {
        checkbox: "Please check at least one.",
    }
});
```

Hope it help!

Comment: are you doing everything in the right way? It works because is part of a project made by me.

Comment: @anilkumar You should put more effort into your comment.  Saying, "its not working," (I'm ignoring the spelling error for now) does not really give anyone useful information to attempt to help you.